# Wikitude: Custom Heading and Location

Tags: geolocation, wikitude

I intend to use Wikitude SDK to create an app that would use more precise values retrieved by the GPS and Heading.

What ways are there to inject my custom values (i.e. created by a custom made precision increasing algorithm) into Wikitude SDK / ARchitectWorld?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wikitude SDK only supports injecting a custom location. There is at the moment no possibility to inject a heading.